# How to pass two strings to javascript with loadURL

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I am trying to call a javascript function from my webview while giving it two strings.
But one of the strings is always null. In my java code it isnt.

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:SelectTargetDirectory('" + fileName + "', '" + fileSizes + "')");
```

That is what I am doing but with no success

Here the Javascript side:

```
selectTargetDirectory = function (fileName, fileSizes) {
     $.ajax({
         url: "/UploadFileProductsDialogController/ShowUploadDialog",
         data: { fileName: fileName, fileSizes: fileSizes },
         success: function (result) {
             Controller.ProcessResponse(result);
         },
         error: function (error, response) {
             alert(error);
         }
      );
};
```

Comment: Unrelated: your selectTargetDirectory is different from javascript:SelectTargetDirectory.

Comment: Further down it saved into SelectTargetDirectory

Comment: What is the type of `fileSizes`?

Comment: I think **fileSizes** is always null